# How to retain edited Textbox value after submit?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

My Scenario,

I reloaded ny page with previous data that was available for my login.Now i try to edit the textbox and update .It either updated or doesnt retain the edited value in Textbox.

```
objConn.Open() 
Dim myControl As TextBox = FindControl("txtName") 
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("sp_UpdateNewmember", objConn) 
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure 
cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Username 
cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@FirstName", DirectCast(myControl, TextBox).Text))
cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtlastname.Text
```

Anyone can help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a page is requested very first time, you have to fetch a row from the `table` and assign values to the controls properties.

```
protect Sub Page_Load()
  IF Not IsPostBack Then
     //Retrieve a record
  End If
End sum
```

To update a record, code should be like this:

```
Dim myControl As TextBox = FindControl("txtName") 

Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("sp_UpdateNewmember", objConn) 
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure 

cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.VarChar,30).Value = Username 
cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName",SqlDbType.VarChar,30).Value= myControl.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.VarChar,30).Value = txtlastname.Text 
objConn.Open() 
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
objConn.Close()
```

Comment: Sorry for disturbing.. Now when i login to my page i see my records in respective fields. When i edit my field and update my form it brings the same value in textbox to update.I checked through break point.How can make this error cleared.

Comment: @Sammy - You should have to write page_load code in side the IsPostBack block.

Answer (score 0):

please write code inside this

```
 if (!ispostback)
    {
       //code
    }
```